# Right way to build out JSON config for Restful Web Service

Tags: javascript, json, rest, jquery, configuration

I know the question is a little vague, but I'm not sure how to explain it.

I'm building a [sencha-touch](/questions/tagged/sencha-touch) app that will be communicating with an ASP.NET MVC WebService.

Instead of putting all the restful URL's all over the place within the app, I'm thinking of setting up a config file that will contain the WebService information. Below is what I have so far.

```
var config = {
    WebService: {
        Url: 'http://webservice.myapp.com/',
        Vimeo: {
            Read: 'Vimeo/Read'
        },
        Contact: {
            Communicate: 'Contact/Communicate',
            Contact:'Contact/Contact'
        }
    }
};
```

And though this works, when I setup my JSONP Request, it looks a little funny.

```
$.ajax(config.WebService.Url + config.WebService.Vimeo.Read, {
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            videosToShow = data;
        });
    }
});
```

Is there a better/right way to approach this?

Comment: I don't think it looks funny... Is there a reason why you split the URL into two pieces?

Comment: well because I'll be using dozens of services, and I don't want to put the domain portion of the RESTful URI in the config over and over.

Comment: then I think you've done a fine job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sort of decided to go a different direction.

I've built a method called `WebService(controller, action)`

Whereby I submit it as follows

```
$.ajax(WebService("myController", "myAction"), {
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            // do stuff
        });
    }
});
```

Works like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery ajax object is a good general wrapper for xmlhttp, but since you're building additional level of abstraction why not wrap $.ajax in your own object which accepts a config type and handles the ajax and any errors that may result gracefully.

You could design it so your calls looked something like:

```
root.ajax(config.WebService.Vimeo.Read, callback);
```

You could then configure the url root in your wrapped ajax object once on startup.

```
root.ajax.rootUrl = config.WebService.Url
```